# Error: unexpected '}' in "}" in an if condition

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying do a for loop with an if statement. It didn't work, so I took out the "if" condition. I made it work. That is, the following code

```
if (data$mis[3] = "mis") {
print ("George Bush")
   }
```

Outputs "Geoge Bush"

However, it also says:

> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Please check the `=` and it should be `==`..  Also if the 'mis' column is `factor`, do `if(as.character(data$mis[3]) == "mis"){ ...}`

Comment: You don't have a semicolon ; `print("foo");`

Comment: @RobinKnaapen semi-colons are typically not necessary in R as the character return suffices. The exception is when you want to include multiple commands on a single line.

Comment: @lmo i could swear that the tags said something php ish, but my bad.

Comment: Did you get an error before that, that said `Error: unexpected '=' in "if (data$mis[3] ="`?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue of the logical operator.  It should be `==` and not `=` (which can also be used as assignment)

```
 if (data$mis[3] == "mis") {
    print ("George Bush")
 }
```

It is not clear about the `class` of 'mis'.  If it is `factor` class, convert to `character` before doing the logical operation

```
 if (as.character(data$mis[3]) == "mis") {
        print ("George Bush")
 }
```

EDIT: A Typo in the second `for` loop fixed

Comment: `factor(c("a", "b")) == "b"`

Comment: you probably should put `==` instead of `=` in your second `if` statement. That is only if you don't want to throw an error of course...